# Which sequence type is better for a comparison and why? (Python)

Tags: python, types, comparison, sequence

I have a condition that compares one object to several others, like so:

```py
if 'a' in ('a','b','c','e'):
```

The sequence was created for this purpose and doesn't exist anywhere else in the function. What are the pros and cons to grouping it as a tuple, list, or set, given that they all seem to work the same and the list is short? Which would be idiomatic?

Comment: If you have only four values a tuples is find, for larger quantities use set, you can define a set literal like `{'a','b','c','e'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use a set until you have good reason not to.* (And then use a list.)

I would consider a set to be more idiomatic. It conveys the meaning more clearly, since order doesn't matter, only membership.

And to be clear, a set is a *collection* but not a "sequence type" (even though it's iterable), because it's semantically "unordered".

---

Why not use a set?

Sets may only contain *hashable* types. And, this is important, they will raise a `TypeError` instead of simply returning `False` when you ask if an unhashable type is in the set. If you might get an unhashable object on either side of the `in` operator, you're out of luck. Sometimes you can use hashable elements instead (like `frozenset` instead of `set` or `tuple` instead of `list`), sometimes you can't.

But tuples and lists don't have to hash their elements.

---

Why a list over a tuple?

The main advantage of a list that they avoid a syntactic quirk for tuples of one element. Say you have `('foo', 'bar')` and later decide to remove the `'bar'`. Then you have `('foo')`. Oops, see what I did there? It was actually supposed to be `('foo',)`. It's easy to forget the comma. And the `in` check still works for strings like `('foo')`, since `in` checks for substrings. This can subtly change the meaning of your program. `'oo'` is in `('foo')`, but not in `('foo',)`.

A one-item list like `['foo']` doesn't have that problem. [And as 
user2357112 pointed out, a constant list is going to get compiled to a tuple anyway.]

Note that a one-item set, like `{'a'}` doesn't have that problem either. An empty `{}` is a dict instead, but that's not going to cause any issues with an `in` check because it's also an empty collection.

But you should arguably be using `==` instead of `in` when comparing against only one element.

---

That's it for clarity. Now for the micro-optimizations. Early optimization is the root of all evil. Don't optimize at the expense of readability before it's actually necessary.

A set lookup is faster if it's not too small, since a tuple's elements have to be checked one-by-one which (on average) grows with the size of the tuple, while a set is backed by a hashtable (like a dict), which has a small constant overhead. If the distribution of cases isn't uniform, this means that the order of elements in the tuple matters a lot. Putting the more common cases first in the tuple will make the checks much faster than the reverse, on average.

How small does the collection have to be to for the set's constant overhead to matter? Profile and see. Performance can vary based on a lot of factors. It's not just the number of elements, but how long an equality check takes, and where they're located in memory, etc.

A tuple should have a slightly smaller overhead both in memory and construction time than the other collections. But the construction overhead doesn't really matter if the compiler can make it load as a saved constant value. (This can happen when all the elements are themselves constant at compile time. You can use the `dis` module to confirm this is happening.)

Comment: That `is_foo` trades set creation overhead for function call overhead. At this level of microoptimization, function call overhead matters. (Also, CPython has an optimization that preconstructs and saves a frozenset for `thing in {'set', 'of', 'constants'}` expressions.)

Comment: (The optimization also preconstructs and saves a tuple for `thing in ['list', 'of', 'constants']` and `thing in ('set', 'of', 'constants')`.)

Comment: @user2357112 Tried it out with `dis`, and yep, frozenset or tuple constants, at least in CPython 3.7. Didn't know about that optimization. Can you elaborate on the function call overhead? Compared to no function at all, sure, but I assumed it was in a function anyway. Is a function with a default argument going to be any worse than one without?

Comment: I'm comparing `is_foo(x)` to `x in {'a', 'b', 'c', 'e'}`, not to another function call.

Comment: Sure, that `x in {'a', 'b', 'c', 'e'}` check would probably be in some function, but I think someone trying to apply the advice in this answer is more likely to directly replace their `x in (bunch, of, stuff)` checks with an `is_stuff(x)` call than to add a `_stuff_set` default argument to their existing function and write `x in _stuff_set`. (Also, adding a default argument to the existing function raises the chances of errors being hidden by default arguments.)

Comment: There's no point in using the default argument as a constant if the compiler does it anyway. I'm trying to edit that section now.